# composite primary key with 1 foreign key jpa, toplink

Tags: jpa, toplink

I need to create on composite primary key which will have one foreign key
ComponentMarks Class:

```
@IdClass(SubQuesCompIDs.class)
@Entity
@Table(name="component_marks")

public class ComponentMarks {
     @Id
     private String component_ID;
     @Id
     private String question_ID;
     @Id
     @ManyToOne(targetEntity=ConsolidatedMarks.class)
     @JoinColumn(name="submission_unique_ID", referencedColumnName="submission_unique_ID")
     private ConsolidatedMarks consolidatedMarks;
//***********getters and setters***********
}
```

SubQuesCompIDs  class:

```
public class SubQuesCompIDs implements Serializable{

    private ConsolidatedMarks consolidatedMarks;
    private String component_ID;
    private String question_ID;
/****************getters and setter************/
}
```

ConsolidatedMarks  class:

```
 public class ConsolidatedMarks {
   @Id
   private String submission_unique_ID;
   /****************getters and setter************/
   }
```

error:

```
   Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
    Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [RDEVAL_MySQL_DB] failed.
     Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-7150] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))):       oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
      Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [com.eta.entityBeans.SubQuesCompIDs] and those of the entity bean class [class com.eta.entityBeans.ComponentMarks] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified id elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class. 
   java.lang.Exception: 
    Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: WebappClassLoader
     context: /ProjectName **
     delegate: false
   ----------> Parent Classloader:
  java.net.URLClassLoader@26b418

   Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
    Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [RDEVAL_MySQL_DB] failed.
     Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-7150] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
      Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [com.eta.entityBeans.SubQuesCompIDs] and those of the entity bean class [class com.eta.entityBeans.ComponentMarks] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified id elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.
```

and also in java class "ComponentMarks" at "@IdClass(SubQuesCompIDs.class)" it was showing this compilation error message:

```
   The attribute matching the ID class attribute consolidatedMarks does not have the correct type com.eta.entityBeans.ConsolidatedMarks
```

ConsolidatedMarks is from the package com.eta.entityBeans.

Update ComponentMarks :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="component_marks")
 @IdClass(SubQuesCompIDs.class)
 public class ComponentMarks {
    @Id
    private String component_ID;
    @Id
    private String question_ID;
    @Id
    @Column(name="submission_unique_ID")
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="submission_unique_ID")
    private ConsolidatedMarks consolidatedMarks;
    /****************getters and setter************/
    }
```

updated SubQuesCompIDs :

```
    public class SubQuesCompIDs implements Serializable{
    private String  consolidatedMarks;
    private String component_ID;
    private String question_ID;
    /****************getters and setter************/
    }
```

now the second error which is compilation error is not comming.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "derived identity".

Your `@IdClass` should look like this:

```
public class SubQuesCompIDs implements Serializable{

    private String consolidatedMarks;
    private String component_ID;
    private String question_ID;
/****************getters and setter************/
}
```

Note the field corresponding to the `@ManyToOne` `consolidatedMarks` field has the same field name but its type matches the type of the `ConsolidatedMarks` primary key field.

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have modified my code according to ur sugeessions but I am getting the same error  `
" Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [com.eta.entityBeans.SubQuesCompIDs] and those of the entity bean class [class com.eta.entityBeans.ComponentMarks] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified id elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class"`

Comment: I am adding my table creation code also.
CREATE TABLE `component_marks` (
 `submission_unique_ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `component_ID` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 `question_ID` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

Comment: I'm not sure it is causing the error, but you should not have the annotation `@Column(name="submission_unique_ID")` on the field `consolidatedMarks`.